# Jquery Accordion changing Fontawesome icons on click

Tags: jquery, font-awesome, jquery-ui-accordion, removeclass

I have a very simple accordion which I have added in a font awesome icon to with the class .fa-angle-down.

I've added a toggleClass so when the .accordion-toggle is clicked it rotates the icon 180 so its pointing up rather than down.

What I need help with is adding in the next bit which says that if any other .accordion-toggle have the class .rotate180 then remove it.

I have tried this-

```
$(".fa-angle-down").not($(this)).removeClass('rotate180');
```

But it just removes the class from all... Help?

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
  $(this).toggleClass('active')
  $(".fa-angle-down").toggleClass('rotate180')

  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  $(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass('active');

  });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find all which have the class and then remove it like this

```
$("#accordion").accordion();

$('#accordion .accordion-toggle').click(function () {

    // Whatever other code here too

    //Remove all rotate180
    $('.rotate180').removeClass('rotate180');
    //Now just add it for 'this'
    $(this).children('.fa-angle-down').addClass('rotate180');
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/md3hd/

Comment: This gives the same issue as my example. It closes all, even the one you've just clicked on to open. I need to target all instances of it other than the one that is clicked on...

Comment: Please post all your javascript code, I can't see the part you 'tried' in the rest of the code your showed?

Comment: Hi Rob, if you take another look I have written "I have tried this - " then put a line of code.
So I have posted all my javascript, agreed?

Comment: No not agreed, where have you *tried* that?! In the other block of code?

Comment: I tried it after the last line, before the two }); Is me answering this helping you to help me at all?

Comment: Yes, I am not just being acrimonious! :-) Just busy building a fiddle to help you understand a bit better!

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out - I wasn't using .find to target what I needed.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

$(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$(this).find('.fa-angle-down').toggleClass('rotate180');

$(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
$(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass('active');
$(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).find('.fa-angle-down').removeClass('rotate180');

});
  });
```